# 3.5" ios app screens get messed up on 4" screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My first app got accepted and uploaded onto the app store today :) 
I download it onto my 4s (iphone with a 3.5 inch screen size) it is PERFECT!!
But when i download the app onto my iphone 5 (iphone with 4 inch screen size) the pictures are all out of place and moved around on the screen (as if the images are being stretched. How can i fix this? I dont have time right now to redo all of the art work. I just want the black bars to be on the top and bottom. How can i achieve this? Thanks a bunch guys!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Retina (4-inch) launch image from the project navigator (although it would be better to provide an 4-inch version of your app :p ).

Comment: I did this, however it still isnt working properly! Any other ways to fix it? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @AlexMoyer Could you clarify what isn't working? If you properly remove the 4 inch launch image from Xcode, the app will run with black bars on any 4 inch device.

Comment: Yes, sir. I posted a picture of the xcode project showing the removed image. Also, i deleted the default@2x... picture from my project, when i submitted my app, and when i test it on my 4" screen device i still don't see the black bars. Thanks for the help Jack!